# How to convert a system of parametric equations?

Tags: equation-solving, parametric-functions

I have a system of parametric equations (t is a parameter)

```
    z = ((1 - t)^2 (1 + 4 t - 2 t^2))/(2 (1 - 2 t + 2 t^2))
    y = ((-1 + t) Sqrt[1 - t^2] (1 - 3 t + t^2))/(1 - 2 t + 2 t^2)
    {t, 0.7071, 1}
```

[image: plot]

I am going to find the normal equation of z=f(y) without parameter t. How can I do this in Mathematica? As I told before, I found only y=f(z) as analytical expression like:

```
    Y = ((Sqrt[3] a1 - 6 a2) Sqrt[-a1^2 + 4 Sqrt[3] a1 (2 + a2) - 
    12 a2 (4 + a2)] (-a1^2 + 4 Sqrt[3] a1 (-1 + a2) - 
    12 (-4 - 2 a2 + a2^2)))/(
    96 Sqrt[3] (a1^2 - 4 Sqrt[3] a1 (1 + a2) + 12 (2 + 2 a2 + a2^2))),
```

where :

```
    a1 = Sqrt[(2^(2/3) a^2 - 4 a (-3 + 4 Z) + 2 2^(1/3) (3 + 4 Z)^2)/a],
    a2 = Sqrt[
    2 - a/(6 2^(1/3)) - (8 Z)/3 + (8 Sqrt[3] Z)/a1 - (3 + 4 Z)^2/(
    3 2^(2/3) a)],
    a = (-54 + Sqrt[k] + 1080 Z - 576 Z^2 + 128 Z^3)^(1/3),
    k = -139968 Z + 1150848 Z^2 - 1396224 Z^3 + 470016 Z^4 -221184 Z^5
```

but for my task I need z=f(y).

Comment: Have you looked at `Eliminate[]`?

Comment: yes, but there is no elimination.

Comment: What do you mean? Is there no result returned?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Please show your code in the Question.

Comment: `Eliminate` chokes on the expression as it is given by the OP. I have not tried any manipulation though.

Comment: You really should provide code that is correct (the commas make the above not parse correctly) and complete (the code for the parametric equations is missing).

Answer (score 4):

Here is the implicit equation satisfied by `(y,z)`.

```
ratpolys = {z - (1 - t)^2 (-2 t^2 + 4 t + 
        1)/(2 (2 t^2 - 2 t + 1)), 
   y - (t - 1) *Sqrt[1 - t^2]*(t^2 - 3 t + 1)/(2 t^2 - 2 t + 1)};
gb = First[
  GroebnerBasis[ratpolys, {y, z}, t, 
   MonomialOrder -> EliminationOrder]]

(* Out[93]= -135 y^4 - 1728 y^6 + 1024 y^8 - 720 y^4 z + 1536 y^6 z - 
 360 y^2 z^2 - 4768 y^4 z^2 + 4096 y^6 z^2 + 160 z^3 - 112 y^2 z^3 + 
 3840 y^4 z^3 + 720 z^4 - 6176 y^2 z^4 + 6400 y^4 z^4 - 320 z^5 + 
 3584 y^2 z^5 - 2880 z^6 + 4608 y^2 z^6 + 1280 z^7 + 1280 z^8 *)
```

One can use `Solve` to get branches of algebraic roots for either variable in terms of the other.

Comment: Ah, this was what I was going to suggest to the OP after verifying that `Eliminate[]` did not work for his example…

Comment: ...but Solve cant get algebraic roots z=f(y): Solve[-135 y^4 - 1728 y^6 + 1024 y^8 - 720 y^4 z + 1536 y^6 z - 
   360 y^2 z^2 - 4768 y^4 z^2 + 4096 y^6 z^2 + 160 z^3 - 
   112 y^2 z^3 + 3840 y^4 z^3 + 720 z^4 - 6176 y^2 z^4 + 
   6400 y^4 z^4 - 320 z^5 + 3584 y^2 z^5 - 2880 z^6 + 4608 y^2 z^6 + 
   1280 z^7 + 1280 z^8 == 0, z].

Comment: The result, in terms of `Root` objects, is comprised of algebraic roots. That's by definition of what an algebraic root is. They are not in terms of explicit radicals but that's a different matter.